# How to fix warning 'component uncontrolled' in TextField Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried using *TextField* of Material UI as a controlled component with React, according to documentation it should work:

```
function SomeFunction (){

const [name, setName] = useState('some value')
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
  }
return (
<>
<TextField sx={{width:'50%'}} value={name}
 onChange={handleChange} id="outlined-basic" label="Имя" variant="outlined"/>
</>
)
}
export default SomeFunction
```

But have a warning **A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.**
How to fix this, please?

Comment: Could you show your actual code? This one doesn't make sense since you are not returning anything if this is a function, and if it's not a function, but a JSX snippet then the JS code is misplaced.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox so it could be re-created easily?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: This component looks fine, are you certain the error is coming from this one?

Comment: When I'm using plain html input no error, but need to use TextField.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `TextField` to this

```
<TextField 
   sx={{width:'50%'}} 
   value={name || ''}
   onChange={handleChange} 
   id="outlined-basic" 
   label="Имя" 
   variant="outlined"
 />
```

Comment: Same story, not working

Comment: This warning usually comes when you give TextField an initial value as 'undefined' and then try to change it to some value. Vishnu's answer makes sense, as the undefined value is replaced by empty string initially. Make sure you are using value={name|| ''}. Other than that share the actual code you are using.